# Print only unique values inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code snippet:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="val in myObj">
   <td>{{val.Action}}</td>
   <td>{{val.Tx}}</td>
   <td>{{val.Qty}}</td>
   <td>{{val.Price}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I want to print `{{val.Action}}` only if it is the first unique value in the list. Else I want to print empty space `""`. Is it possible to do this by creating a filter? Or any other way?

Comment: can you add an example

Comment: It can be done using angular filter or you can use $filter in your controller and do it, do you want a sample code for this to understand?

Comment: Yes. Sample code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by checking previous element(`items[$index-1]`) and, if it's `Action` field equals current one(`items[$index-1].Action == val.Action`) you should write empty string, otherwise value. For correctnes of this algoritm, you should implement sorting by this field. As you have `filter` and `orderBy`, you can't just write `myObj[$index-1]`, because `myObj` array and filtered&sorter array(`items`) not the same, so you should apply assigning: `items = (myObj...`

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myObj = [
      {Action:'Action3', Tx:4, Symbol: 'a' },
      {Action:'Action1', Tx:1, Symbol: 'c' },
      {Action:'Action2', Tx:3, Symbol: 'b' },      
      {Action:'Action3', Tx:5, Symbol: 'a' },
      {Action:'Action1', Tx:2, Symbol: 'c' },            
      {Action:'Action3', Tx:6, Symbol: 'a' }
    ];
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
   <input type='text' ng-model='someValue' ng-init='someValue="a"'/>   
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="val in items = (myObj | filter : { Symbol: someValue } | orderBy: 'Action')">
       <td>{{(items[$index-1] && items[$index-1].Action == val.Action) ? '' : val.Action}}</td>
       <td>{{val.Tx}}</td>
       <td>{{val.Symbol}}</td>       
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is cool, but my ng-repeat is like this:  <tr ng-repeat="val in MyObj | filter: { Symbol: 'someValue' } | orderBy: ['Action']">. How do I incorporate val in items = (myObj | orderBy : 'Action') into that?